# Fire the MouseUp event even when outside control in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, mouseevent

I want to be able in my WPF application to detect the `MouseUp` event from anywhere. That is to say, if the user clicks in the control and holds his click, then releases it outside the Control, I want my `MouseUp` event to fire.

I have done the `MouseDown` event, it works, but the MouseUp event isn't fired if released outside the `Window`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the [CaptureMouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse.aspx) method in your MouseButtonDown handler

You can look up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771301.aspx) on what it actually does.

Comment: You should call `ReleaseMouseCapture` on MouseButtonUp too

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using the windows API's for mouse_event described here: 
[Simulating Mouse Clicks](http://www.jarloo.com/simulating-mouse-clicks-in-c/)

I would use the CaptureMouse listed above first but if that doesn't work for you this one should.